# How do we logically know that there are not 2 Gods (according to the Chovos HaLevavos)?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, faith-bitachon-emunah

The Chovos HaLevavos in Shaar HaYichud Chapter 7 in the paragraph's that start "The 3rd way" and "The 7th way" explains why it makes sense for there to be only one God and not (none or) two.

1- Can someone please explain to me what he means? How, according to the Chovos HaLevavos, do we know that there are not 2 Gods?

2- Does anyone argue with his thinking and reach the same conclusion in a different way?

(2 other places that might be useful to look at with regards to this topic is 1)Emunos Ve'Deos by R' Saadia Gaon, HaMaamar Harishon Perek 3 the paragraph that starts "Acharei kein hisbonanti" and 2) Moreh Nevuchim, Chelek Aleph, end of chapter 76)

Answer (score 1):

it is summarized here (according to the translator's very limited understanding) http://dafyomireview.com/398#sum where it says "the third premise states that anything composite cannot be eternal..." (I happen to be the translator BTW)

Basically what he is saying is that only that which is truly infinite can be eternal and if there were two gods, then neither one would be truly infinite since each one would be bounded in some way hence neither could be eternal.

Comment: So how do we know that composites can't be eternal and why do we assume 2 gods would bound each other and why do we assume that the gods must be limitless?

Comment: @ClintEastwood 1. see the link. if that's not clear. see ch.5-10 there with the commentaries. 2. otherwise it's not 2 gods but 1 god as explained there. 3. if not limitless then not eternal which means it is created, and therefore not God